# PageChooserPanel not showing

Tags: menu, wagtail, submenu

I'm learning django and Wagtail and currently looking to use Streamfield for menus and submenus for a personal site. I modified some code I found via a tutorial video and would want to create a basic menu and submenu. All fields show OK in the Wagtail CMS. The problem is that the pagechooserpanel is not showing in the CMS.  I'm not sure what's wrong and how to fix it. I'd really appreciate any help with this

```
class MenuItemBlock(blocks.StructBlock):

    link_title = blocks.CharBlock(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        max_length=50
    )

    link_url = blocks.CharBlock(
        max_length=500,
        blank=True
    )

    link_page = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailcore.Page",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )
    
    open_in_new_tab = blocks.BooleanBlock(default=False, blank=True)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("link_title"),
        FieldPanel("link_url"),
        PageChooserPanel("link_page"),
        FieldPanel("open_in_new_tab"),
    ]

    @property
    def link(self):
        if self.link_page:
            return self.link_page.url
        elif self.link_url:
            return self.link_url
        return '#'

    @property
    def title(self):
        if self.link_page and not self.link_title:
            return self.link_page.title
        elif self.link_title:
            return self.link_title
        return 'Missing Title'

    class Meta:
        icon = 'plus'
        label = 'Menu Item'
        # template = 'menu_item.html'


class SubMenuBlock(blocks.StreamBlock):
    sub_menu_items = MenuItemBlock()

    panels = [
        FieldPanel("sub_menu_items")
    ]

    class Meta:
        icon = 'list-ul'
        label = 'Sub Menu'
        # template = 'sub_menu.html'


@register_snippet
class Menu(ClusterableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from="name", editable=True)

    menu_items = StreamField([
        ('MenuItem', MenuItemBlock()),
        ('SubMenu', SubMenuBlock()),
    ], blank=True, use_json_field=True)

    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel("name"),
            FieldPanel("slug"),
        ], heading="Menu"),

        FieldPanel('menu_items', heading='Menu Items')
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ForeignKey` is only valid on Django models, not StreamField blocks. Also, `panels` definitions are not valid on blocks and will be ignored.

You should use `PageChooserBlock` instead:

```
link_page = blocks.PageChooserBlock(required=False)
```

Additionally, the keyword arguments `blank` and `null` are not valid on `CharBlock` - the equivalent is `required=False`. See [the StreamField blocks reference](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/streamfield/blocks.html#field-block-types) in the Wagtail docs.